# ios-in app purchase transaction issue

Tags: ios

Using in app purchase 
    http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_in_app_purchase.htm

```
-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue 
 updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
    switch (transaction.transactionState) {
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
                NSLog(@"Purchasing");
            break;                
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
           if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier 
              isEqualToString:kTutorialPointProductID]) {
               NSLog(@"Purchased ");
               UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:
               @"Purchase is completed succesfully" message:nil delegate:
               self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
               [alertView show];
            }               
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
            break;                
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:               
            NSLog(@"Restored ");               
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
            break;                
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
            NSLog(@"Purchase failed ");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
}
```

in in-app purchase i requested product after the called updatedTransactions?

Comment: Are you asking about payment from Apple or payment from your card when you purchase the in-app item?  The transactions and payments are shown in iTunesConnect

Comment: @Paulw11 yes but i'm not sure why i'm not getting amount of all user even only get few person's amount